# What is the difference between FWHH and FWHM?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, terminology, signal-processing

The title says it all really. I wanted to know if there is a situation where full width half height half maximum is more appropriate than full width half height or vice versa.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. They mean exactly the same thing.

(In English the terminology "full width half maximum" is more common, but in other languages sometimes the term is more closely translated to FWHH, such as the French [LMH](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largeur_%C3%A0_mi-hauteur).)